# sklearn SGDClassifier's decision_function odd behavior

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

So I am using a simple SGDClassifier on the MNIST dataset (as per the Hands-on ML book) and I can't seem to figure out the behavior of its decision_function.

I changed the last line of the original_decision function to specifically check if anything was different. The variables with suffix "check" are the ones returned by the decision_function here. The code:

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_mldata
mnist = fetch_mldata("MNIST original")
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
from sklearn.utils.extmath import safe_sparse_dot
from sklearn.utils import check_array

X, y = mnist["data"], mnist["target"]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = X[:60000], X[60000:], y[:60000], y[60000:]

shuffle_index = np.random.permutation(60000)
X_train, y_train = X_train[shuffle_index], y_train[shuffle_index]

# converting the problem into a binary classification problem. 
y_train_5 = (y_train == 5)
y_test_5 = (y_test == 5)

sgd_clf = SGDClassifier(random_state=42)
sgd_clf.fit(X_train, y_train_5)

# modified decision_func to ouput vars
X_check, coef_check, intcpt_check = sgd_clf.decision_function([X_train[36000]])

print((X_check == X_train[36000]).all())
print((coef_check == sgd_clf.coef_).all())
print((intcpt_check == sgd_clf.intercept_).all())

# using same funcs as used by decision_function to calc. 
# i.e. check_array safe_sparse_dot
X_mod = check_array(X[36000].reshape(1,-1), "csr")
my_score = safe_sparse_dot(X_mod,sgd_clf.coef_.T) + sgd_clf.intercept_
sk_score = safe_sparse_dot(X_check, coef_check.T) + intcpt_check

print(my_score)
print(sk_score)
```

Here is the output (for a single run):

```
True
True
True
[[ 49505.1725926]]
[[-347904.18757136]]
```

Here is the modification I made to the decision_function (2nd last line before the commented out original one):

```
scores = safe_sparse_dot(X, self.coef_.T,
                                 dense_output=True) + self.intercept_
return X, self.coef_, self.intercept_
#return scores.ravel() if scores.shape[1] == 1 else scores
```

Even though the 3 entities involved (instance X, coefficients, intercept) all match to be true with my variables, the multiplication still leads to vastly different outcomes.

**Why is this happening?**

Edit: Curiously I found out that if I comment out the two lines responsible for shuffling the dataset namely:

```
shuffle_index = np.random.permutation(60000)
X_train, y_train = X_train[shuffle_index], y_train[shuffle_index]
```

The problem disappears...

Comment: Please don't post links to screenshots of data.  It's harder to help you, and you're much less likely to get a timely response.  Instead, post example data inline, as part of a [Minimum, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its probably due to X_mod using the original "X" (unshuffled) matrix while X_check uses the X_train(shuffled) index.

i.e. X_train[36000]!=X[36000] so of course, your scores should not be the same.

Comment: I feel stupid even after half realizing that permutations remove the error :D Haha. Well thanks! Got it.

Answer (score 0):

And maybe propably due to the absent line:

```
np.random.seed(42)
```

you have used a random state for your model but didn't use any for the permutation

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)
shuffle_index = np.random.permutation(60000)
X_train, y_train = X_train[shuffle_index], y_train[shuffle_index]
```